# Exporting regressions to latex with different covariance matrices in R

Tags: r, regression, covariance, stargazer, standard-error

I would like to know if there is a way to use the `stargazer` package, or any other similar package, to export regression tables from R to latex using two different covariance matrices.

When I say two different matrices I mean using both robust and clustered standard errors, for example, and exporting something like this

```
coefficient                 1.5***
(robust standard error)     (0.3)
(clustered standard error) [0.45]
```

Now I am generating two `stargazer` tables and manually adding rows from one to another.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e., your code and data that runs with your code.

Comment: In my experience this is an unconventional way to report these results, why not run two side-by-side specifications (i.e. with and without clustered SE)?